# ClickOnce analog

Tags: deployment, desktop-application

I am looking for a ClickOnce analog on Windows platform. I have to deploy (publish) a .NET WinForms application (thick client) for N-tier system via web.

Comment: What's wrong with ClickOnce itself?

Comment: @Dean Harding it is just perfect tool for monkey applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are deploying on Windows clients, why not just use ClickOnce - it is built into the Visual Studio IDEs since VS2005.

Alternately, if you would like to consider a cross-platform solution, try [ZeroInstall](http://0install.net/).

Comment: +1 It seems, it's a great tool. I am going to try it. Thanks.

Comment: You're most welcome! :)